# GORM - Is it able to get all queries that will execute before calling `.commit`

Tags: go, go-gorm

Currently, I am working with GORM
Is it possible to get all the query gonna execute if I press commit

For example :

```
tx := db.Begin()
tx.Create(&user1)
tx.Create(&user2)

=> Get all the query will be commited
=> INSERT INTO user VALUES (...)
=> INSERT INTO user VALUES (...)

tx.Commit() // Commit user1
```

Because I need to write down something like :

User 1 at `time` run `function A`, which result in making queries

```
=> INSERT INTO user VALUES (...)
=> INSERT INTO user VALUES (...)
```

Yes, I could just add a creator in my table to check it. But for now I need to do it in this way. Please help.